# trapping the event when a messagebox is closed and using as delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, delegates

The following works fine for a windows form.

It simply uses a delegate to reactivate a GroupBorder on the *parent* form when the *child* form is closed.

```
    private void uxUpdateDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = false;
        uxBindingNavigator.Hide();
        uxFormDatabase myNewDisplay = new uxFormDatabase();
        myNewDisplay.FormClosed += delegate { activateGroupBorder(); };
        myNewDisplay.Show();    
    }

    public void activateGroupBorder() 
    {
        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = true;
        uxBindingNavigator.Show();
    }
```

Is it possible to do the equivalent to the above but for a messagebox instead of the child form?

This is my attempt which is not the solution:

```
    private void uxAuthorPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = false;
        uxBindingNavigator.Hide();
        MessageBox myMessage = new MessageBox;
        myMessage.close += delegate { activateGroupBorder(); };
        myMessage.Show("hello world"); 
    }
    public void activateGroupBorder()
    {
        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = true;
        uxBindingNavigator.Show();
    }
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(...)` is synchronous call, i.e. execution doesn't continue further until box is closed. Why can't you just call your activateGroupBorder() after the message box is done?

    `myMessage.Show("hello world");
    this.activateGroupBorder();`

Comment: +1 Cool - thanks. Why don't you put that as the solution?

Comment: I've added green tick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show(...)` is synchronous call, i.e. execution doesn't continue further until box is closed. Why can't you just call your `activateGroupBorder()` after the message box is done? E.g.:

```
MessageBox.Show("hello world"); 
this.activateGroupBorder();
```